# Recuperar valor Chosen Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho dois Select Chosen em meu form, o que estou fazendo é:

[image: Inserir Item]

Ou seja, ao digitar se não localizar nada relacionado, tenho o link 'incuir item', que me abre um modal, até tudo funcionando.

O grande problema é que, preciso transferir o texto digitado para um input que está no modal, não consegui fazer, mas, acredito que tenha haver com esta linha, dentro do arquivo chosen.jquery.js.

```
return this.results_none_found = this.form_field.getAttribute("data-no_results_text") || this.options.no_results_text || "Nada encontrado <br><br> <a href='#' id='chama_modal_motivo_servico' class='chama_modal_motivo_servico' >Incluir este item</a>";
```

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sNniffer/5ctjt6ug/**

Comment: Dizes na pergunta "preciso transferir o texto digitado para um input que está no modal". Onde está esse input? onde está o modal e o link "incluir item"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvido,

Alterando a linha 886 do chosen.jquery.js.
É possível recuperar o conteudo do select com a variavel, terms.
O que fiz foi, pegar o valor da terms e passar para o href do link.

```
var valor_input = terms;
no_results_html = $('<li class="no-results"> Nada Encontrado ' + this.results_none_found + ' "<a href="#" id="chama_modal_motivo_servico" class="chama_modal_motivo_servico" data-id="'+ valor_input +'"><span></span></a>"</li>');
```

Comment: Explica pf a resposta para outros que tenham o mesmo problema aprenderem e compreenderem melhot a solução.

Comment: @sNniffer como você fez?

Comment: Opa amigao, basta criar um modal,alterar a linha 886 do chossen.jquery.js. Nesta linha que tem o retorno caso nao encontre o resultado. Basta alterar o conteudo do retorno